# MS Access randomly(?) has problems opening my report

Tags: database, vba, report

I have been working with MS Access for some days now, and I have noticed that sometimes errors appear on certain actions (mostly apparently pertaining to VBA code), while I really have not changed anything.

The most annoying instance of this problem is the following example: 
This was an existing DB, and I created a new "smarter" report. When I go through the forms, eventually generating my report, about half the time there is no problem, and my fancy new report appears at the end without any problems

Yet other times I get "Run-time Error '2427': You entered an expression that has no value", and my report does not open. As far as I can see, this occurs entirely at random. I did not change any code or query's, it can even happen when just closing the report, and then trying to directly open it again.

Is this just some weird bug in Access or something?

Comment: You should file a bug report with Access. This sort of thing is out of scope for SO.

Comment: did you check the solutions in Google search?

Comment: Did you search for Error 2427 on google?  If you did at the very minimum you should add the details here.  If not you should before asking your question here?

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue like yours not too long ago. Being a flat file system ms access is fragile, and I would recommend doing a compact/repair to your file when closed (not just set compact on close). Good luck.